# List of numeric pairs - need strategy to multiply and sum products

Tags: python

I have a list of number pairs as follows:

```
my_list = [(0,9),(1,5),(0,12),(2,8),(1,13),(2,17)]
```

I need the dot product based on the first number of each pair as a match key. In other words, I'll multiply the `9` and `12` because the `0` matches. I'll set this aside and add the product of the next match (`5 * 13`, because they match on the value `1`).

I have an ugly solution which requires I know the length of the list:

```
print my_list
dotproduct = 0
i = 0
for ml1 in my_list:

  for ml2 in my_list:
      if ml1[0] == ml2[0] and ml1[1] != ml2[1] and i < 4:
        print 'multiply ',ml1[1] ,' and ', ml2[1]
        dotproduct += ml1[1] * ml2[1]
        print 'count = ', i
        i += 1
print dotproduct
```

This will also only work if the operands of the product are not equal. In short, it works when the length of the set is known and the product operands are not the same. Pretty weak.

In case it's not obvious, I'm a beginning Python person.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that any number that appears as the first number in a pair does so in exactly two input pairs?

Comment: If you're doing numeric work with lists of values, you might want to check out [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org), which makes almost everything you want to do more readable, more concise, and faster and with less memory. Or, if you're trying to do a lot of grouping/aggregation work, maybe [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org).

Comment: It is assumed each 'first number' appears only twice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done very simply with [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects):

```
from collections import defaultdict

out = defaultdict(lambda: 1)

for key, val in my_list:
    out[key] *= val
dotproduct = sum(out.values())
```

For your example input, this gives me `dotproduct == 309`.

Comment: Great solution johnsharpe, Thank you. This is the first question I've posted. If I don't give you proper 'props' let me know what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: Now that I'm evaluating this I realize in my list of pairs, which actually represents a sparse matrix, not every first number in my set will have a 'mate'. These need to be dropped. It's not evident this is happening.

Comment: @JohnLigda in that case, make a dictionary `{key: [val1, val2, ...]}` then only process those where `len(d[key]) > 1`. `defaultdict(list)` will make this easier.